# Two Spree Commerce apps on localhost, interfering with each other's user authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I'm running two Spree Commerce 2.0.4 apps along side each other, one on localhost:3000, the other on localhost:3001. I'm using Webrick. The first is a default install - `spree install --auto-accept`. The second is a default install with just a few very basic theme modifications and database changes (it has a different admin email / password). Both are using Spree's devise authentication method (ie, the default).

Both apps run alongside each other just fine, as long as I don't log in. If I login on one, it works fine, until I login on the other, when I'm auto-logged out from the first, and logged in OK on the second. So, I can only be logged in on one at a time.

Ideally, I'd like to be logged in as admin on both at the same time, without them interfering with each other.

I just started another (non-spree) Rails app on localhost:3002. It's a simple blog, using devise for auth, and it's authentication system doesn't seem to be affected by the two spree apps. So, the issue seems to be specific to the spree apps.

Any ideas as to what could be the problem, or how I can run two spree apps locally without them interfering with each other's user authentication?

UPDATE: I just tried making both spree installs have an admin account with the same email / password, and logging in with that account. However, the same issue remains - logging in on one app logs me out on the other.

Comment: Have you tried to use two different browsers? Such as Chrome for 3000, Firefox for 3001 ?

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought of that myself. I just tried it, and it works. If you add that as an answer I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use two different browsers. Such as Chrome for 3000, Firefox for 3001.